# Can `SpringApplicationBuilder` be used to wire parent/child relationships between `@SpringBootApplication` and `@SpringBootTest`?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

The following allows the app to start:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyMain.class)
      .run(args);
}
```

but once I add a `@SpringBootTest`-annotated class as a child, startup fails due to various beans not being found:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyMain.class)
      .child(MySpringBootTest.class)
      .run(args);
}
```

How can such a relationship be wired?

Context: We want a Spring Boot App to contain some end-to-end tests and be able to run these tests. Simply having the application use the `JUnitRunner` to execute the `@SpringBootTest` winds up with non-unique bean definitions (or something similar).